# RecyclerView styling at theme level

Tags: android, listview, styles, android-recyclerview, themes

I'm trying to implement generic style parameters for `RecyclerView` at **theme** levels. As in contrast to `ListView`, I used something like this:

*Defined a style:*

```
<style name="StyleListView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView">
     <item name="android:requiresFadingEdge">vertical</item>
     <item name="android:fadingEdgeLength">10dp</item>
     <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
</style>
```

*and later used in my custom theme:*

```
<item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/StyleListView</item>
```

This works perfectly fine for `ListView`. However, I'm unable to reflect this for `RecyclerView` as I thought it would work for any type of list.

So, is there any predefined style attribute available for `RecyclerView`, for example **`android:recyclerViewStyle`** or anything?

If not, then how can I achieve this at theme level?

Comment: May be http://stackoverflow.com/a/24580870/1920735 can help.

Answer (score 12):

> RecyclerView styling at theme level

RecyclerView now has a default style attribute: `recyclerViewStyle`, which allows setting of the default style in your theme

The following attributes are supported

```
    <!-- Class name of the Layout Manager to be used. -->
    <attr name="layoutManager" format="string" />
   
    <!-- ============================= -->
    <!-- Attributes for Layout Manager -->
    <!-- ============================= -->
    <attr name="android:orientation" />
    <attr name="android:descendantFocusability" />
    <attr name="android:clipToPadding" />
    <attr name="spanCount" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="reverseLayout" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="stackFromEnd" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="fastScrollEnabled" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable" format="reference" />
    <attr name="fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable" format="reference" />
    <attr name="fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable" format="reference" />
    <attr name="fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable" format="reference" />
```

To use the above feature, add/update the following dependency in your build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta05'
}
```

You can see the commit [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/f5936cfb7e303297ec33748bd5e0eaf512ad2fd4/recyclerview/recyclerview/res/values/attrs.xml).

### Example:

**1. Define your default style**

```
<style name="DefaultRecyclerViewStyle">

    <item name="layoutManager">androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="spanCount">2</item>

</style>
```

**2. Add the above style into your default theme**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="recyclerViewStyle">@style/DefaultRecyclerViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

Thats, all. You have defined an application wide default style for your RecyclerView widgets.

Answer (score 10):

There's not an equivalent to `listViewStyle` for `RecylerView`, unfortunately.

I think the best you can do is define a style for your `RecyclerView`, then have whichever views you want to use that style use `style="@style/RecyclerViewStyle"` (if you're just wanting to define a couple attributes like in your example).

If you really just don't want to have to do that for every `RecyclerView`, then you'd have to subclass it and return a non-zero parameter for `defStyle` in the constructor. You'd have to replace all instances of your `RecyclerView` in XML with your newly subclassed class, though.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jason Robinson says you can subclass RecyclerView in this way, replace `RecyclerView` with `RecyclerViewStyleable` in xml and then style it with `recyclerViewStyle`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="RecyclerViewStyleable">
        <attr name="recyclerViewStyle"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

-

```
public class RecyclerViewStyleable extends RecyclerView {
    public RecyclerViewStyleable(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RecyclerViewStyleable(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.recyclerViewStyle);
    }

    public RecyclerViewStyleable(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this changelog](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview#1.1.0-beta02) on August 7th, 2019, `RecyclerView` adds a `recyclerViewStyle` style attribute, which behaves similar to `listViewStyle`.

Add it to your `build.gradle`:

```java
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta02'
    ...
}
```

Note: You'll need to use AndroidX, which is a part of [Android Jetpack.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack)